# SAPUI5 Smart Table select all rows of a group

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table with grouping enabled.And I need to select all the rows for a particular group by clicking on the group header row (or even add a button in the group header row if possible ).

Is there any way to do that.

[image]

Need to select all rows for a particular group ( Marked in Red Circle) by clicking on the row or from any way